# Detecting AVAudioSession sampleRate changes

Tags: objective-c, audio, avaudiosession

How can you detect a change to the `AVAudioSession sampleRate`?

We configure our app's audio graph using the current sample rate of the audio session. However, if our app goes into the background another app can change the sample rate, and sometimes we get noise that we believe is caused by not correctly resetting our audio graph to the new sample rate that is in use.

We haven't found any notifications or other ways to determine when the AVAudioSession's sampleRate changes.